# NTLMSetUserInfo on Windows CE 6

Tags: windows-ce, ntlm, user-accounts

I want to create my own user configuration utility targetted for WinCE6 in C++.  All the NTLM functions ([such as this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926215.aspx)) require `ntlmssp.lib` which I cannot find.  I have searched my Platform Builder directories but can only find the dll file not the lib.

Can anyone shed some light on how I actually access these functions, or find the lib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib is probably generated (the DEF is in public\common\oak\lib) when you build your platform to only include the entry points you've selected in your design.  For example, I do see ntlmssp.lib in my release directory for a couple designs.

The proper way to do this is to roll and install an SDK based on your OS Design, then you'll get that installed in the right place on your dev machine (or make your utility as a subproject of your OS Design, which will then look in the release folder for the LIB).

Comment: I found it in there shortly after I posted.  It must have been hiding in plain sight.